# Detect if there is an emoji in a message. Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, but I can't find one. I want to be able to detect if there is an emoji in a message. I've tried checking if the message content starts with `:` and ends with `:` as well as starting with `<:` or `<a:` and seeing if it ends with `:>` or `:`. Either way, neither of those worked because the bot did do what I coded if one of those messages contained the beginning of an emoji (`:`, `<a:`, etc.).
This is the code I used and I did not get any errors from it.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(":") && message.content.endsWith(":")) return;
if (message.content.startsWith("<:") && message.content.endsWith(":>")) return;
if (message.content.startsWith("<a:") && message.content.endsWith(":>")) return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `String.prototype.match()` function, you can match regex within a string.
If you don't know about regex, it's like what you're doing (checking if it starts with : and ends with :, etc.) but it works much more efficiently. I am not skilled enough to give you the specific regex on the fly, but it's an important skill to learn yourself anyway so look up some tutorials and use regex101.com to test it.

Once you have regex that matches emojis, you can simply do message.content.match(emojiRegex) to see if it has an emoji!

EDIT: The benefit to this is that, unlike what you were doing with startsWith() and endsWith(), which would only work if your message is just an emoji with no other text before or after, using match() and regex lets you match it even within the middle of a string.

Comment: May be also helpful if you will add some example(s).